# HighCharts stacked grouped chart - with grouped caregories plugin

Tags: highcharts

Have an issue, probably I have mixed more things, then should be, but anyway it will be nice to figure this out.

Have an fiddle link with with code sample below

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function () {
          var index = this.index;
          var legendName = this.name;
          var series = this.chart.series;
          series.forEach(function(el, index){
            if(legendName == el.name) {
              if(el.visible)
                el.setVisible(false);
              else
                el.setVisible(true);
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
      },
    },
  },

  yAxis: [{
   labels: {
      format: '{value} $',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'First Y Axis',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
      }
    },

  }, {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Second Y Axis',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },

  }],

  xAxis: {
    labels: {
        rotation: -90,
          groupedOptions: [{
          rotation: 0,
        style: {
            rotation: 0,
        }
    }],

  },
  categories: [
     {
       name:'Apples', 
       categories: ['male', 'female']
     },
     {
       name:'Oranges', 
       categories: ['male', 'female']
     },
     {
      name:'Pears', 
      categories: ['male', 'female']
     },
     {
       name:'Grapes', 
       categories: ['male', 'female']
     },
     {
       name:'AppBananasles', 
       categories: ['male', 'female']
     }]
    },

    series: [
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        stack: 'female'
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        stack: 'female'
    },
    ]
})
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/9o64ybo4/

Using here highcharts and one of the highcharts plugins - grouped-categories plugin.
I have here some categories and subcategories and planned that 1-st subcategory (male) should appear below the first columns, and second one (female) should appear below the second column and so on.

As You can see there I have lost 2 top level categories like (Grapes and AppBananasles).

Any suggestions will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a category to the point explicitly.

```
 series: [
            {
        name: 'John',
        data: [[0, 5], [2, 3], [4, 4], [6, 7], [8, 2]],
        stack: 'male',
   //     pointPlacement: 0.15
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [[0, 3], [2, 4], [4, 4], [6, 2], [8, 5]],
        stack: 'male',
   //     pointPlacement: 0.15
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [[1, 2], [3, 5], [5, 6], [7, 2], [9, 1]],
        stack: 'female',
   //     pointPlacement: -0.15
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [[1, 3], [3, 0], [5, 4], [7, 4], [9, 3]],
        stack: 'female',
  //      pointPlacement: -0.15
    },
    ]
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/9o64ybo4/1/

Point placement allows to move a column to the right/left, it may be needed because you have two stacks and each category create an empty space for the second stack.

The other approach, without different stacks, could be reorganise the data a little by adding null values.

```
 series: [
            {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, null, 3, null, 4, null, 7, null, 2, null],
//        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, null, 4, null, 4, null, 2, null, 5, null],
//        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [null, 2, null, 5, null, 6, null, 2, null, 1],
//        stack: 'female'
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [null, 3, null, 0, null, 4, null, 4, null, 3],
 //       stack: 'female'
    },
    ]
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/9o64ybo4/2/

Comment: Perfect ! Both approaches can be used, but I like 1-st one more :) Thanks